# R: Is there an alternative SVM implementation than libsvm in e1071 package?

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I try to compare different implementations of SVMs in R. Is there another one than the libsvm implementation in the e1071 package ?

Generally, is there a good alternative from libsvm which implements the nu-SVM and epsilon-SVM ?

Answer (score 10):

Check the [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) package:

> kernlab: Kernel-based Machine Learning Lab
>
> Kernel-based machine learning methods for classification, regression,
>   clustering, novelty detection, quantile regression and dimensionality
>   reduction. Among other methods kernlab includes Support Vector
>   Machines, Spectral Clustering, Kernel PCA, Gaussian Processes and a QP
>   solver.

Kernlabs `ksvm` supports C-svc, nu-svc, (classification) one-class-svc (novelty) eps-svr, nu-svr (regression) formulations along with native multi-class classification formulations and the bound-constraint SVM formulations.
`ksvm` also supports class-probabilities output and confidence intervals for regression.

An interface to the `SVMlight` implementation is provided in package [klaR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/klaR/index.html)

See also the CRAN Task View *[Machine Learning & Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html)*